# HTML inside JSON

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm using an API to get some data, but one of the JSON values, contains HTML inside of it. Is there a way for me to use the HTML tags that are inside the JSON value exactly like they are shown, instead of having to make the exact same HTML tags in my MVC view, and editing these ones out? If this wasnt descriptive enough heres an example of what i mean:

This is just one of the JSON values, I didnt wanna paste the whole thing:

```
"detail": "<h1>Overwatch Patch Notes – October 19, 2016</h1>\r\n\r\n<p>A new patch is now live on Windows PC. Read below to learn more about the latest changes.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>To share your feedback, please post in the <a href=\"http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/22813879/\" target=\"_blank\">General Discussion</a> forum.<br />\r\nFor a list of known issues, visit our <a href=\"http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/22813881/\" target=\"_blank\">Bug Report </a>forum.<br />\r\nFor troubleshooting assistance, visit our <a href=\"http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/22813880/\" target=\"_blank\">Technical Support</a> forum.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Please note that these changes will be rolled into a larger patch for PlayStation 4 and Xbox One at a later date.</p>\r\n\r\n<h2>BUG FIXES</h2>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>General</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Fixed an issue causing the default Overwatch spray to override a player’s chosen spray when watching a Play of the Game or Highlight</li>\r\n\t<li>Fixed an issue causing players to frequently disconnect while viewing Highlights</li>\r\n\t<li>Fixed a bug preventing the appropriate music from playing after a loss on the Junkenstein's Revenge Brawl</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Gameplay</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Fixed a bug causing multiple issues when displaying data on the leaderboards</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Heroes</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Fixed an issue preventing Ana’s Nano Boost callouts from being heard by the enemy team</li>\r\n\t<li>Fixed a bug preventing players from receiving credit toward the Healing Done commendation when healing D.Va’s mech</li>\r\n\t<li>Fixed a graphical issue that was preventing the liquid in Mei’s Endothermic Blaster from appearing</li>\r\n\t<li>Fixed a bug causing Reinhardt’s Charge to unexpectedly stop when crossing certain thresholds (e.g. when exiting a dropship)</li>\r\n\t<li>Increased the volume of Roadhog’s “Want some candy” voice line</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Map</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Fixed a bug on Eichenwalde that caused some textures to stretch across the map for some players</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw` inside your view to use the raw string value:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.detail);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: And in a matter of seconds, you made my life a whole lot better!